# how to define spring beans for list of user defined classes?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-bean

I am new in spring.Using jdk 1.7. I have defined a class :

```
public class FileDetails {

String filePath;
String fineName;
String timeStamp;

    public FileDetails(String filePath, String fineName, String timeStamp) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
    this.fineName= fineName;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}

}
```

And trying to create list of this class from another class in the same package as :

```
public class otherClass{

    @Autowired
private List<FileDetails> fileInfo;

    public void addToList(){
        fileInfo.add(new FileDetails("something","something","something");
   }
}
```

And this is my application context:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>



<bean id="fileDetails" class="pacckageName.FileDetails" >
</bean>

</beans>
```

I am getting error:

```
 null pointer exception on the line "fileInfo.add(new FileDetails("something","something","something");"
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: In what package `FileDetails` class does reside ?

Comment: They are in the same package. And I am not getting issue with any other beans but this one. I am sure that's because of the List. I probably have to define the class with some annotation. But not sure what.

Comment: For starters, you appear to be using Spring 2.5. The current version is 4.0. Additionally, you haven't provided accurate information, because you have case mismatches that are likely relevant. Finally, the best approach for your goal is probably Java configuration with a modern Spring version.

Comment: Is it a compile time error ?

Comment: run time error. null pointer exception. Looks like the list is not being initialized.

Comment: This is because you create bean of class `FileDetails` (it is OK), but try to inject (`@Autowire`) bean of class `List`, which does not exist. Spring cannot find candidate bean for autowiring, neither by class (`List`), nor by name (`fileInfo`). So you got NULL.

Comment: Eugene, no you don't. You get an exception because you ask to autowire something and no candidate could be found.

Answer (score 0):

`OtherClass` is not a managed bean. You are probably doing `new OtherClass()` somewhere in your code.

A managed bean is an instance that is managed by Spring,  because it is either

- discovered through component scanning (`OtherClass` annotated with `@Component` and a component scan directive in your application context)
- created explicitly in the application context (i.e. alongside your `FileDetails` bean)

When you run `new OtherClass()`, it's a regular instance that you have created, Spring is not aware you created it and there's no way for it to process annotations such as the `@Autowired` one.

So you end up with an instance just like if Spring was not there at all and, as you can see, your list is therefore `null`.

`@Autowired` on a collection locates all **managed** beans of the type of the collection and gathers them in a collection that is injected. If no item is found, an exception is thrown unless you set the `required` flag of the annotation to `false`.

Last note, your example for `FileDetails` has no empty constructor and your bean definition does not provide any argument either. This is not supposed to work, I guess you removed part of the code in your description.